# Need to restart IIS 7 after fuill web deployment

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I would just like to find out which is the best practice when deploying to IIS 7 with ASP.Net 2 applications.

We deploy around 7 WCF net.tcp consumed web services on IIS 7 and then also have a website running under IIS 7.

When we deploy with TFS we copy over the released code to the specified folders under IIS. Would the best practice be to then also reset IIS or because IIS recompiles the JIT everytime the assemblies change, you don't actually need to restart the server or any pools.

Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to reset IIS.  You are right in guessing that this is unnecessary because it will recompile automatically as necessary, and the app pool will reset if the web.config or anything in \bin is changed..